# Function return unexpected result

Tags: javascript

I write a simple function which is one of exercise from book about JS that I currently read.

```js
function range(start, end) {
    let array = [];

    for(start; start <= end; start++) {
        array.push(start)
    }

    return array;
}

function sum(array) {
    let result = 0;

    for(let i = 0; i <= array.length; i++) {
        result += array[i];
    }

    return result;
}
```

I use `sum(range(1, 10))` and it's return `NaN` instead of `55`. So why its not return a number but `NaN`?

Comment: `<= array.length`? This will like mean that `array[array.length]` is being added. Which is `undefined`

Comment: When you run this using a debugger, what is the *first* point that it behaves unexpectedly?

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on how to debug your code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`i <= array.length` should be `i < array.length`. The array begin from zeroth index, so the last element will be at index `array.length - 1`.

```js
function range(start, end) {
    let array = [];

    for(start; start <= end; start++) {
        array.push(start)
    }

    return array;
}

function sum(array) {
    let result = 0;

    for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        result += array[i];
    }

    return result;
}

console.log(sum(range(1, 10)));
```

Comment: I didn't notice it. Thanks :)